# The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from pool

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have problem with my homework code. We must create some database with updating users, but I am getting error with these and program crash.. 
This is full error code and there is code..

> Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): error
>   connecting: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because
>   all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I try with  query.CommandTimeout = 60; but i think its useless, what do u think?

```
MySqlConnection connect = new 
     MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Work;Uid=root;Pwd='1234';");
connect.Open();
MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE user  
        SET User_Name=@User_Name,User_BankBalance=@User_BankBalance,
        User_Password=@User_Password,LottoTimer=@LottoTimer 
        WHERE User_Name='" + Escape(u.Username) + "'", connect);
using (query)
{
    query.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", Escape(u.Username));
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_BankBalance", u.BankBalance);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Password", u.Password);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LottoTimer", u.LottoTimer);
    query.Dispose();
    query.Prepare();
    query.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connect.Close();
return;
```

Comment: Why do you dispose the command and then continue to use it? Consider to enclose the MySqlConnection object in the using statement. Failing to dispose the connection could lead to using too many connections object from the pool

Comment: Try putting full path of Database including the extension of the filename.

Comment: Why don't you use a parameter for the WHERE clause? This is totally vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

You method should look something like this:

```
        string query =
            @"UPDATE user SET"
            + " User_Name=@User_Name,"
            + " User_BankBalance=@User_BankBalance,"
            + " User_Password=@User_Password,"
            + " LottoTimer=@LottoTimer"
            + " WHERE User_Name='" + Escape(u.Username) + "'";
        using( var connect = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Work;Uid=root;Pwd='1234';"))
        using( var query = new MySqlCommand(query, connect))
        {
            connect.Open();
            query.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", Escape(u.Username));
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_BankBalance", u.BankBalance);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Password", u.Password);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LottoTimer", u.LottoTimer);
            query.Prepare();
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return;
```

It is important to dispose the MySqlConnection, so it can be available to the pool again. The problem you have is that all connections are used in the pool, and it is waiting for one - until the timeout.